# Joomla takes 10 to 15 minutes to update site

Tags: update

I've seen from others that Joomla is supposed to make changes to the live site as they happen (or at least when you save.) For some reason, for me Joomla takes 10 to 15 minutes to update all of the changes. My Cache settings are Cache - off  Cache Handler - file  and Cache time - 15.

Can anyone think of why Joomla would do this or could it be something with my server host? I have tried on several different computers and several different web browsers if that helps narrow things down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the admin view, go to Extensions > Plugins menu and search/find the system cache plugin.  My guess is it's active, and regardless of whether you've enabled cache in your global parameters; if this plugin is active Joomla will enable some core caching functionality.

Disable this system cache plugin and retest by performing an edit, saving and checking the change immediately populates on the front end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @BrianBolli So when would you want to enable this plug-in?